# Excel query/macro , delete records where the aggregate value is not over 100

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with about 5000 records. I need to delete out the records where the Amount column is less than $10.00 unless the aggregate of the amount column is greater than or equal to $100. I have an ID column that matches to the name on the record. So is it possible to create something that for each ID number in the ID column if the Amount column is less than $10 delete it unless the same ID appears again and is greater than $100? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `ID` column is say A and the `Amount` column say D, each with a label,  then a helper column with:

```
 =SUMIF(A:A,A2,D:D)
```

in Row2 copied down to suit should identify (less than $100) those rows that should be deleted.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try it with my columns =SUMIF(X:X,X2,AH:AH)  ? X is my ID and AH is my cost column

Comment: It is just a generic popup that states "your formula contains an error" try the following. I am using =SUMIF(X:X,X2,AH:AH). When I use your example there is no error. But my ID and cost columns are reflected by X and AH

Comment: Ok that works, but I must be missing something. Is there something else I need to do because the formula is not giving me any values. Do I need to reference $100 somewhere? I just pasted the formula in the last column

Comment: They are just in general format, so no formatting. So I have a header row 1 where column X is called ID and column AH is called cost. Then in the last column on row 2 I have your formula so I must be missing something else?

Comment: No $ found, I tried copying just 3 rows to a new sheet and same thing. The formula is there but not calculating anything. Thanks for your help with this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73185/discussion-between-user1342164-and-pnuts).

Comment: the data you are trying to sum is not number try this function:   =SUMPRODUCT((X:X=X2)*--(AH:AH))

Comment: Thank you pnuts for your help as well